# unable to set cookies in front end even in postmen cookies are working fine when made a fetch request

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, frontend, fetch

cookies code

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + oneDay),
    secure: false,
    signed: true,
    sameSite: 'None',
})
```

fetch code

```
 try {
        const response = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    withCredntials: true,
                    credentials: 'include',
                },
                body: data,
            }
        )

        const responseData = await response.json()

        console.log(responseData)
        console.log(await document.cookie)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

Cors module

```
const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://127.0.0.1:5500', // Add your frontend origin here (Don't add '/' at the end)
}

//config
app.use('*', cors(corsOptions))
```

I am getting the response back from server with user ID cookies are not being set